# Relationship between bundle and xcode file hierarchy for iOS applications

Tags: ios, xcode

Can someone explain to me the relationship between what you see in xcode and your iOS application's bundle?

For example if I create a folder inside xcode called Resources and copy some pictures into it, how will that relate when I try loading the pictures using `[[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];`

I'm trying to have some kind of organized way of having folders full of an unspecified amount of images and then load them with `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:]`

I'm pretty sure the file hierarchy that you see in xcode is not duplicated in your app's bundle. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: App bundle for which O/S?

Comment: Operating system? iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XCode, the items placed in the main bundle are all place in the top level unless you choose option "Create folder references for any added folders" rather than the default "Recursively create groups for any added folders".

[iPhone SDK: subFolders inside the main bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398459/iphone-sdk-subfolders-inside-the-main-bundle)